# Vim vertical split window not rendered correctly

Tags: split, tmux, ssh

Not sure if it's related to vim configuration, tmux settings or ssh config, I opened a file with vim on a remote server, and every time when I use `:vsp` command to split a vertical window, the right window sometimes is not rendered correctly, and some lines in right window will go across the borderline to the left window, as shown in the attached picture.

I tried to disable all `.vimrc` including `~/.vimrc` and `/etc/vimrc`, it happens the same. No idea how to debug this cause I am not an expert of Vim nor tmux nor ssh.

Could anybody show me some hints of how to debug this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! For debugging, I recommend (a) [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) and (b) finding a deterministic, reproducible way of triggering the issue (which might include designing experiments to find out if Tmux or SSH are related). The best (b) is "minimal" and includes only the necessary steps to show the problem.

Comment: What version? What terminal?

Comment: ctrl + l may fix it